# JodaTime toDate gives wrong date

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Today I found a very mysterious bug in the code. I have used the JodaTime library for a while and it has been consistent ever since.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateHelper.formatDateTime("25/06/2012");
TestHelper.spot(dateTime);
TestHelper.spot(dateTime.toDate());
```

Results -

```
2012-06-25T00:00:00.000+05:30
Mon Jun 25 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

But in a different java application -

```
2012-06-25T00:00:00.000+05:30
Sun Jun 24 18:30:00 GMT 2012
```

### DateHelper.formatDateTime() method

```
public static DateTime formatDateTime(String text) {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    return format.parseDateTime(text);
}
```

The only issue I suspect is the format (GMT and IST). What can I do to maintain consistency.

Comment: It's an expected behaviour. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: How can I set GMT universally?

Comment: @Duli Petition every government to change their local timezone rules? But seriously, you can't change things without causing _something_ to break. Make the code that you control be accurate and locked down, rather than trying to get everything else to change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put a VM parameter stating

```
-Duser.timezone="+05:30"
```

And after I removed it everything is working like normal. But the problem now is that I can't connect to Oracle 9i database. It's giving me the below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region  not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The two values represent identical time instants. They're just rendered differently because of different timezones. This is *purely* a matter of rendering; once again, they are the *same time*.

To reliably convert a `DateTime` to a consistent “human-readable” string, you need to specify the timezone, format and locale when rendering:

```
String rendered = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
                          .toString("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Of course, you should use the `ISODateTimeFormat` if you want a computer to parse the results though; that's both consistent and somewhat human-readable at a pinch. (It sorts easily too.) Only use other formats when readability is more important than anything else.